# Php mail() is not sending mail to hotmail user but working with all others

Tags: php, html, sendmail, phpmailer, hotmail

I am sending mail using `php mail()` function from my dedicated server through php script. Script is sending mail to all email users except hotmail users. Here's my code for `mail()` function

```
$hyperlink = 'http://test.guru99.com/';
$to ='user@hotmail.com';
$subject ='Test Mail';
$message = '<p>For Testing open '. $hyperlink .'</p>';
$headers = 'From: user@domain.com';
$headers .= ' Career Guru99'. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This code is working fine for all email users `(like gmail, yahoo, hosted domain)` but not for hotmail users. My script and code is correct. I think my headers are correct but I couldn't find the cause. I want to send mail with html formatted.

I checked the server logs, the error I ma getting is "Message could not be delivered. Please ensure the message is ***RFC 5322 compliant"***

I have checked online and tried to set various headers for the email but did not work

Please give me Suggestions.

Comment: does it go in their spam?

Comment: It doesn't send or messages go to SPAM? Also, if they did not send, how much time passed since the execution of script? Some messages can get delayed for about an hour

Comment: @DanielA.White It doesn't go to spam as well.

Comment: @mariobgr More than 2 hours passed but still mail isn't delivered.

Comment: The real suggestion is don't use mail. Go get something like PHPMailer or something if you need to use PHP scripting. It sets up everything you need to do and has been designed for years to get it right. Just not worth doing it on your own as things like this are bound to happen and your host provider will eventually ban you if you don't watch all the rules

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797626/php-mail-function-cannot-send-to-hotmail

Comment: “doesn't work” is not a valid problem description.

Comment: i would recomend you to check mail delivery logs.

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact error I get

Comment: How to check server logs?

Answer (score 2):

Your emails are certainly sended (since it works for the other users), but Hotmail is probably rejecting your emails thinking it's spam.

Hotmail is known to be a PITA when it comes to emails... You can check if you have correct DKIM and SPF parameters, see if your server isn't blacklisted, or better yet, use a mailing provider like MailChimp, SendGrid or similar to be sure your emails are sended in best conditions.

EDIT : about the RFC compliant, you could try changing your "from" header like this :

```
$headers = 'From: User <user@domain.com>';
```

Comment: The issue is with RFC 5322 compliance as per server logs...

Comment: Great, It's worked!! Many Thanks, But mail is going into junk, how can i avoid it?